# How to compare Rails enum types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have the following enum model in my Rails (4) application:

```
class Dual < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum dual: [:dual, :not_dual]

  validates :dual, uniqueness: true
  validates :dual, presence: true
end
```

And I have another model which has many `Duals`:

```
class SillColour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sill_colour_duals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :duals, through: :sill_colour_duals
end
```

I want to be able to test if an instance of `SillColour` has a `Dual` enum. This is all I could get to work:

```
dual = Dual.find(1)
not_dual = Dual.find(2)

sill_colour.duals.include?(dual)
sill_colour.duals.include?(not_dual)
```

Obviously this is extremely unreliable as the ID of the Duals could be anything in production (for testing IDs are fixed). I tried this:

```
dual = Dual.where(dual: 0)
not_dual = Dual.where(dual: 1)
```

and even given the database duals table looks like this:

```
 id | dual 
----+------
  1 |    0
  2 |    1
```

My tests fail and it seems to be because `dual` and `non_dual` are no longer comparing correctly. I've examined them using pry and they appear to be the same as before, but clearly they're not.

Surely there must be a better way? I envisaged being able to do this:

```
sill_colour.duals.include?(Dual.dual)
sill_colour.duals.include?(Dual.not_dual)
```

but this doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `sill_colour.duals.any? {|d| d.dual?}` and `sill_colour.duals.any? {|d| d.not_dual?}`

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick! Although Rubocop doesn't like it:

'Pass &:dual? as an argument to any? instead of a block.'

I'm investigating.

Comment: Instead of block: `sill_colour.duals.where(dual: Dual.dual['dual']).any?` returns true or false. Aren't you looking for a true or false response?

Comment: Also, `Dual.dual['dual']` looks nasty. You might want to change dual enum to something like `dual_status` if you are allowed to do so. So the statement above will be `sill_colour.duals.where(dual_status: Dual.dual_status['dual']).any?`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer with a code from my app

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:dual, :not_dual]

  # see scopes
  scope :dual, -> {where(status:  Contact.statuses['dual']) }
  scope :not_dual, -> {where(status:  Contact.statuses['not_dual']) }
end
```

Now console, check if a User instance has a contact with dual status:

```
2.1.5 :001 > u = User.last
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "...", ...> 
2.1.5 :003 > u.contacts.dual
  Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND "contacts"."status" = 0  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []> 
2.1.5 :004 > u.contacts.not_dual
  Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND "contacts"."status" = 1  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

As you can see both return empty array, so calling `any?` on empty array will return false both. Because I don't have any contact with status dual or not_dual, let's create one.

Find a contact:

```
2.1.5 :005 > c = Contact.last
  Contact Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts"   ORDER BY "contacts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  => #<Contact id: 3, user_id: 1, ..., ...., status: nil>
```

Set it as dual:

```
2.1.5 :006 > c.dual!
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (15.1ms)  UPDATE "contacts" SET "status" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "contacts"."id" = 3  [["status", 0], ["updated_at", "2014-12-29 13:16:45.576778"]]
   (25.5ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Now check if user has dual or not_dual contacts:

```
2.1.5 :009 > u.contacts.dual.any?
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND "contacts"."status" = 0  [["user_id", 1]]
 => true 
2.1.5 :010 > u.contacts.not_dual.any?
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND "contacts"."status" = 1  [["user_id", 1]]
 => false 
2.1.5 :011 >
```

Checking if user instance has a `dual` enum returns true. In your case instead of user it will be `sill_colour`.

If you don't like scopes you can use `where`:

```
u.contacts.where(status: Contact.statuses['dual']).any?
=> true
```

---

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

```
class Dual < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:dual, :not_dual]
end
```

Having the class as the one above you can check the status like this:

```
dual = Dual.find(params[:id])
dual.dual? # will return true or false depends on the status you set.
dual.not_dual? # same, true or false
dual.status = "dual" # if status was set to 0 or not_dual if status was set to 1
```